# How was a domain in clientRenewProhibited state able to be renewed?

Tags: domains, godaddy

I'm trying to get a domain. It has the following statuses:

```
Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited
Domain Status: clientUpdateProhibited
Domain Status: clientRenewProhibited
Domain Status: clientDeleteProhibited
```

(http://www.icann.org/epp)

Still. The domain is renewed from 19-12-2015 to 19-12-2016. If I'm correct, any request to renew should get rejected instantly for a domain with this these statuses.

Why has this happened?   I was hoping to get this domain for myself, is that still possible? (It's currently property of somebody else.)

Comment: We get questions often from people who want a domain that is already registered. Often, they use some pseudo-legal argument and want to use that as leverage to get the domain. The status notations in your question are actually normal and how registrars lock down a domain to keep it from being hijacked. There is nothing you can do. Let it go and see what domain names are available that you like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`clientRenewProhibited` is a [status applied](https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/epp-status-codes-2014-06-16-en) to a domain by a registrar and tells the domain registry that it should not accept renewal requests directly but only through the existing registrar.

As such the current owner of the domain can only renew the domain through their current registrar and not try and switch providers at the same time as renewing.